# How to fill divs in height

Tags: css

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8sw9/) I'd like to have those divs in right column to fill the height. So the first div should start at the top, and the last should end at the bottom, and the space between each div would be the same. How can I achieve this ?

```
 <div>
<div class="left">
<img src="http://serwer1307713.home.pl/bg.png" />
</div>

<div class="right">
<img src="http://serwer1307713.home.pl/bg-2.png" />
     <img src="http://serwer1307713.home.pl/bg-2.png" />
     <img src="http://serwer1307713.home.pl/bg-2.png" />
     <img src="http://serwer1307713.home.pl/bg-2.png" />
</div>
```

This is how I would like to make it looks like [image]

I've forgotten to add one important info, I need that to be responsive ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean, your images do not reach the end of the page?
Add this to your CSS file:

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

}

Comment: No, look the right column is not the same height as the left one. I'd like to have them the same height.

Comment: Add your suggested fix to his jsfiddle and you can plainly see that it does not solve his problem: http://jsfiddle.net/y8sw9/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy, but I think I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/X3vKd/2/

I added some wrapping divs and used :before and :after pseudo elements to enforce equal heights:

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.wrapper:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like It works ;) I'll use that on website and aprove that ;)

Comment: Ok, it kinda works, but I've forgotten to add one important info, I need that to be responsive ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a height property to your html and your respective divs, then you can manually specify the height for the images in your right or left divs, like so:

```
.left img {
    height: 42%;
}

.right img {
    height: 10%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8sw9/4/

Comment: I cant see any changes ;<

Comment: I just updated the fiddle you posted, it renders fine in my browser

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with js. Have a look 
jsfiddle.net/y8sw9/6/

Comment: what will be the responsive functionality?

Comment: when u resize the window, it should keep ratio

Comment: looks awesome ;) I'll try that, then aprove ;)